# Part of task in a task_group execute on main thread instead of a dedicated thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb, parallel.for

I have a problem with tbb `parallel_for()` and `task_group::run()`.
I have a code which launch a task on thread using `task_group::run()`. In this task, I use `parallel_for()` to parallelized a function.

On the other hand, on the main thread, I do other computation, and at some point, I also call a `parallel_for()` for other stuff.
The problem I have, is that tbb reuse the "main thread" of this second stuff to call code launch before the `group` (without calling `wait()` on `group`).

In my case, it generates problem, I do not want that the first task make some call on the main thread. The reason is due to UI problem, I have some code which test is we are on the main thread or not, to update some UI stuff. And update the UI during the second `parallel_for()` will lead to problem in this specific case.

Here a code which represent the problem :

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

tbb::task_group group;

auto mainThreadId = std::this_thread::get_id();
std::atomic<bool> needWait(true);
std::atomic<bool> taskOnThreadFinish(false);
group.run(
    [&]
    {
        eastl::vector<int> values(20, 0);
        tbb::parallel_for_each(
            values.begin(),
            values.end(),
            [&](int i)
            {
                while(needWait)
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);

                // Should never, ever, never be call on the main thread, but it could be the case in TBB !!!!!!
                assert(mainThreadId != std::this_thread::get_id());

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
            });

        taskOnThreadFinish = true;
    });

eastl::vector<int> mainThreadValues(10, 0);
tbb::parallel_for_each(
    mainThreadValues.begin(),
    mainThreadValues.end(),
    [&](int i)
    {
        needWait = false;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
    });

while(!taskOnThreadFinish)
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
```

So my question is: How to avoid reuse the main thread when the second call to tbb::parallel_for_each() is done?

Note that the code using new std parallel function/behavior work well.

### UPDATE

Using a tbb::task_arena solves the problem, because it isolates the task_group inside the arena.

```
tbb::task_group arena;
tbb::task_group group;

...
arena.execute(
    [&]
    {
        group.Run(
            [&]
            {
                ...
            });
    });
```

Comment: The general axiom is, when subdividing in threads, you don't spin N threads and wait (thereby just wasting a thread to do near-nothing); you spin (N-1) threads and *work*. If you want what you say, launch a separate thread that then runs your parallel for-each.

Comment: Note that this type of reusing is not great also because is the processing is quite slow in the task_group, it will slow down the second parallel_for execute on the main thread.

Comment: This is a pretty clear case of "if it hurts then don't do it".  UI needs to stay responsive, so never let it do anything like call parallel_for().